# Cordova Plugin Touch Id Returning Null On success callback and nothing on error callback

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to check if the device has face id in my ionic app, but the success callback is returning null on biometricType. I'm using cordova-plugin-keychain-touch-id(https://github.com/sjhoeksma/cordova-plugin-keychain-touch-id/blob/master/readme.md)

```
if (window.plugins.touchid) {
  window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable(function(biometryType) {
     console.log("biometry: " + biometryType)
  },
  function(msg) {
     console.log("error: " + msg)
  }
);
```

Ionic Info:

> Cordova CLI: 8.0.0 Ionic Framework Version: 3.9.2 Ionic CLI Version:
>   2.2.0 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0 ios-deploy version: 1.9.2 ios-sim version: 6.1.2 OS: macOS High Sierra Node Version: v8.0.0 Xcode
>   version: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145

Answer (score -1):

Can you give try on this cordova plugin and it is working on my application. 
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id

Comment: Your question should include a minimal working example of the code you want looked at (not just a link to Github) as well as a specific question that can be answered.